# Swift: UIButton textLabel.text value not useable in switch statement

Tags: ios, uibutton, switch-statement, swift

I am new to Swift and iOS development, so I am trying to build a calculator app for learning purposes. However, I am encountering an error. I have titled all of my buttons with the number they represent, so I am retrieving the title in the buttonPress IBAction via sender.titleLabel.text. Then, I pass that into a switch statement to determine if the button was a number or an operator.

```
func handleButton (sender:UIButton) {
switch sender.titleLabel.text {
case "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0" :
    println(sender.titleLabel.text)
default:
    break
    }     
}
```

The error is that sender.titleLabel.text will not bind to the string values I have entered - nor any string values - even though it is  is of type String.

Comment: the following seem to work `sender.titleLabel.text!`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the complier at the moment where Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals cannot be used in switch statements. Instead you can use optional binding to satisfy the compiler. As an extra plus, this will handle the case where titleLabel.text is nil.

```
func handleButton (sender:UIButton) {
    if let text = sender.titleLabel.text {
        switch text {
            case "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0" :
                println(sender.titleLabel.text)
            default:
                break
        }
    }
    else {
        // sender.titleLabel.text is nil
    }
}
```

Comment: @ThoughtfulWizard Actually I think this is a bug with the compiler because technically it is an Implicitly Unwrapped Optional and shouldn't require "unwrapping". For now, the code I suggested satisfies the compiler and even better, it handles the case where the text is nil.

Comment: i think too thats a bug: from the docs „Because the value of an implicitly unwrapped optional is automatically unwrapped when you use it, there’s no need to use the ! operator to unwrap it. “ so it would be nice if you file a bug

Comment: @ChristianDietrich ahah actually i had already filed a bug and completely forgot about it. But I encourage everyone else to do so as well.

Comment: I thought so! I'm glad this is a bug and not my fault.