# Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals in switch

Tags: ios, swift

During a Playground session i've found a **strange error while using Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals in a switch statement.**

I've declared a `Barcode` enum:

```
enum Barcode {
    case UPCA(Int, Int, Int)
    case QRCode(String)
}
```

and made some tries...

### First Try (Working)

The first try uses a **non optional variable definition**

```
var productCode : Barcode

productCode = Barcode.QRCode("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP")

// Working
switch productCode {
case .UPCA(let system, let identifier, let check):
    println("UPC-A with value of \(system)-\(identifier)-\(check)")
case .QRCode(let code):
    println("QRCode with value of \(code)")
}
```

And **it works** with the following console output

> QRCode with value of ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP

### Second Try (Not Working)

The second try uses an **Implicitly Unwrapped Optional**

```
var productCode : Barcode!

productCode = Barcode.QRCode("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP")

switch productCode {
// Error1
case .UPCA(let system, let identifier, let check):
    println("UPC-A with value of \(system)-\(identifier)-\(check)")
// Error2
case .QRCode(let code):
    println("QRCode with value of \(code)")
}
```

and **it fails with the following errors**:

> ```
> Error1: Enum case pattern cannot match values of the non-enum type 'Barcode!'
> Error2: Enum case pattern cannot match values of the non-enum type 'Barcode!'
> ```

### Modified Second Try (Working)

**To make it work i had to unwrap** `productCode` as follows

```
var productCode : Barcode!

productCode = Barcode.QRCode("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP")

switch productCode! {
case .UPCA(let system, let identifier, let check):
    println("UPC-A with value of \(system)-\(identifier)-\(check)")
case .QRCode(let code):
    println("QRCode with value of \(code)")
}
```

**Aren't Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals supposed to access values without the unwrap operator?**

**Why is the Second Try failing** when using `productCode`, an Implicitly Unwrapped Optional variable, without unwrapping it?

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably are missing the fact that the `case` statements do a compare like this: `productCode =~ .UCPA`, so the access of `productCode.UCPA` is working as you expect, but you simply can't compare `productCode`, which is an Optional, to `productCode.UCPA`

Comment: This is a bug, I can't remember where, but this has been found in another SO question as well

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269905/swift-uibutton-textlabel-text-value-not-useable-in-switch-statement/24270143#24270143 Implicitly unwrapped optionals are not unwrapped in switch statements (which is a bug)

Comment: Would you mind replying with an answer so i can accept it and close the question?

Comment: Kind of sucks to close this (very well asked, and researched) question in favor of the other one, even though it turns out they have the same solution :/